# How can I track the Usage time for each app on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing an iOS app where I am trying to get user's **Usage time** of each app,I have seen [Moment](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/moment-track-how-much-you/id771541926?mt=8) App does that even when running in background. I tried to find with apple dev doc, but couldn't find any solid document to get going. I am sure there is a way, but unable to find the right resource.

Please help

Thanks,

Comment: Are they using private APIs, if they are, then how did that go through the review?